# Radiant CMS ruby1.9.2 / rails3 support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, radiant

Does the latest stable Radiant version 0.9.1 (as of 2011.03.26) support the latest stable ruby / rails version (1.9.2p180 / rails 3.0.5)?

Is it safe to run Radiant 0.9.1 with 1.9.2p180 / rails 3.0.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Radiant doesn't support Rails 3 yet. Radiant are using vendor rails, which means the rails is fixed in the Radiant source code. However, there is a branch on Github for Radiant that supports Rails 3, but it is a work in progress.

As for Ruby 1.9.2, Radiant can't use it. When you create a Radiant project, in `script/server`

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
```

This won't work, when your current path is in the root of the project folder, you can either cd to the script directory, then run

```
ruby server
```

Then it should work, else you have to change this `script/server` a bit. This is because `.` is no longer included in the `$LOAD_PATH`, so it will tell you that it can't find `/../config/boot` file (also see this [Rails issue](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2921)).

However, there are some other parts of the Radiant source core that are not really compatible with Ruby 1.9.2. Radiant [recommend using ruby 1.8.6 and 1.8.7](https://github.com/radiant/radiant/wiki/Installation).

Comment: Sorry, I just find out that Radiant source code are not fully compatible with Ruby 1.9.2's syntax. When I run the demo in ruby 1.9.2, and click on tour page, it gives me some error: comparison of String with 60 failed.

Comment: no problem. I have written a post on Radiant vs Refinery http://www.shanison.com/2011/03/29/radiant-cms-vs-refinery-cms/ if you are choosing a CMS for your rails projects.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the latest "stable" radiant does not work with 1.9.x. However, if you install Radiant 1.x (1.0.0.RC4, currently) via `gem install radiant --pre` or by building the gem from source it will work fine or Ruby 1.9.x, and is actually much more stable than 0.9.x.

Rails 3, is still not supported.

The 1.0 release is right around the corner, however, so expect this problem to be solved for the "official" build soon.